# Image upload via web view is not working in Android 6.0 Marshmallow version

Tags: webview

In Web View for registration purposes. In the registration process I have to upload an image from the device. I use various solution for this and it is working properly in every Android version except Marshmallow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you taken permission from mainfeast. I think you did not ask for permission of internal and external storage.